# funcion que detecta colision a traves de la superposicion de divs

Tags: javascript, array

necesito crear una función  en un juego tipo space invaders, que detecte cuando la nave colisiona con algún enemigo,la que tengo no funciona. enemies es el array de enemigos. tanto player como enemies son divs, entonces se me ocurría si se podria comparar la posición de ambos divs para ejecutar el game over, pero no se como se hace.

```
 function collisiondetection(){
        for(var idx=0; idx<enemies.length; idx++){
            if(enemies[idx].top == player.top && enemies[idx].left == player.left){
                window.alert("Game Over");
                window.location.reload();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: He modificado un poco el ejemplo para que se parezca un poco mas a tu código.
Si miras que el "top" y el "left" sean iguales, solo funcionará si se solapan exactamente en el mismo pixel. Deberías tener en cuenta todo el recuadro.
Un sistema fácil de comprobar colisiones, es buscar cuando NO colisionan, ya que una vez compruebas que, por ejemplo, la X del jugador está más allá de la X+ancho del enemigo, ya es seguro que no colisiona y no hace falta comprobar nada mas.
De manera que debes conocer, también, el tamaño de los enemigos.

Aquí te dejo un sencillo ejemplo de colisiones. Clica dentro para que capture el teclado, el recuadro amarillo se mueve con los cursores.

```js
var jugador={top:100, left:100, width:50, height:50};
var enemigo={top:[25,15],left:[25,150], width:[50,50],height:[50,50]};

var teclasPulsadas = new Map;

window.onkeydown = function(info){
    teclasPulsadas.set(info.code);
};

window.onkeyup = function(info){
    teclasPulsadas.delete(info.code);
};

function hayColision(n){
  return !(jugador.left+jugador.width < enemigo.left[n] ||
 jugador.left > enemigo.left[n]+enemigo.width[n] ||
 jugador.top+jugador.height < enemigo.top[n] ||
 jugador.top > enemigo.top[n]+enemigo.height[n]);
}

function buclePrincipal(){
  if (teclasPulsadas.has("ArrowLeft")) jugador.left--;
  if (teclasPulsadas.has("ArrowRight")) jugador.left++;
  if (teclasPulsadas.has("ArrowUp")) jugador.top--;
  if (teclasPulsadas.has("ArrowDown")) jugador.top++;
  
  // Refresca propiedades CSS
  IDjugador.style.left=jugador.left+"px";
  IDjugador.style.top=jugador.top+"px";
  
  var enemigos = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSenemigo");
  for (let n=0; n < enemigos.length; n++){
    enemigos[n].style.left=enemigo.left[n]+"px";   
    enemigos[n].style.top=enemigo.top[n]+"px";
  }

  // Colision
  IDjugador.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  for (let n=0; n<enemigos.length; n++){
    if (hayColision(n)) {
      IDjugador.style.backgroundColor="red";
      break;
     }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(buclePrincipal);
}
requestAnimationFrame(buclePrincipal);
```

```css
.CLASSenemigo {
  position:absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
 }
 #IDjugador {
  position:absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="CLASSenemigo"></div>
<div class="CLASSenemigo"></div>
<div id="IDjugador"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no funciona porque tu condición de `enemies[idx].top == player.top` solo detecta cuando el `top` de ambos divs, son iguales, es decir así

```
____________   ____________
|          |   |          |
|  Player. |   |  Enemy.  |
|__________|   |__________|
```

Es decir a la misma altura. Si por ejemplo quedan así

```
____________   
|          |   ____________
|  Player. |   |          |
|__________|   |  Enemy.  |
               |__________|
```

Tu código actual no lo detecta porque quedan a diferente altura.

Lo mismo pasa con tu condición `enemies[idx].left == player.left`

solo los detecta si llegan a quedar alineados en proporción a la izquierda, es decir así

```
____________
|          |   
|  Player. |   
|__________|

____________
|          |
|  Enemy.  |
|__________|
```

Si llegan a quedar así

```
____________
|          |
|  Player. |   
|__________|

     ____________
     |          |
     |  Enemy.  |
     |__________|
```

Tampoco lo detectaría esa segunda condición.

Por lo que tu código solo los detecta si llegarán a quedar encimados, es decir uno encima de otro, no cuando colisionen.

para la colisión, basta con tocarlos, por lo que necesitaremos varias condiciones que vean si se encuentra en el mismo espacio que algún enemigo.

```
if(
   (
     (player.top >= enemy.top && player.top <= enemy.bottom)
     ||
     (player.bottom >= enemy.top && player.bottom <= enemy.bottom)
   )
   &&
   (
     (player.right >= enemy.right && player.right <= enemy.left)
     ||
     (player.left >= enemy.right && player.left <= enemy.left)
   )
)
```

Basicamente esta condición

```
   (
     (player.top >= enemy.top && player.top <= enemy.bottom)
     ||
     (player.bottom >= enemy.top && player.bottom <= enemy.bottom)
   )
```

Nos asegura que se encuentra en algo así

```
____________   ____________
|          |   |          |
|  Player. |   |  Enemy.  |
|__________|   |__________|
```

O así

```
____________   
|          |   ____________
|  Player. |   |          |
|__________|   |  Enemy.  |
               |__________|
```

O así

```
____________   
|          |   ____________
|  Enemy . |   |          |
|__________|   |  Player  |
               |__________|
```

En cuanto a altura.

En cuanto a horizontal esta revisa

```
       (
         (player.right >= enemy.right && player.right <= enemy.left)
         ||
         (player.left >= enemy.right && player.left <= enemy.left)
       )
```

Que quede así

```
____________
|          |   
|  Player. |   
|__________|

____________
|          |
|  Enemy.  |
|__________|
```

O así

```
____________
|          |
|  Player. |   
|__________|

     ____________
     |          |
     |  Enemy.  |
     |__________|
```

O asó

```
____________
|          |
|  Enemy   |   
|__________|

     ____________
     |          |
     |  Player. |
     |__________|
```

Pero como ambas condiciones deben de cumplirse entonteces solo funcionará cuando ambas se cumplan, es decir que colisione

```
____________   
|      ____|________
|  Play|er |       |
|______|___|Enemy. |
       |___________|


____________   
|__________|
|  Player  |
|___Enemy__|
|__________|

____________   
|          |
|  Player  |
|__________|
|          |
|  Enemy   |
|__________|
```

Comment: muchas gracias, entendí tu explicación, pero no me funciona porque mis enemigos no tienen bottom, solo left y top, al igual que player                                                                var enemies = [
 {left: 900, top: 30},
 {left: 750, top: 60},
 {left: 630, top: 140},
 {left: 480, top: 140},
 {left: 330, top: 60},
 {left: 200, top: 30},
 ]

Comment: Puedes calcular el `bottom` sumando `top + height`, es decir, lo que mide tu div y para el `right`, `left + width` es decir el ancho de tu div.

Answer (score 0):

este es mi codigo completo

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
          #ocean {
            background-image: url("oceano.gif");
            width: 1200px;
            height: 700px; 
        }
    
        .player {
            position: absolute;
            background-image:url("navecita-removebg-preview(1).png");
            width: 80px;
            height: 75px;
        }
    
        .enemy {
            position: absolute;
            background-image:url("enemigo2.png");
            width: 75px;
            height: 75px;
        }
    
        .missile {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: black;
            width: 6px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        </style>
    
      <div id="ocean">
        <div id="players"></div>
        <div id="enemies"></div>
        <div id="missiles"></div>
      </div>
    
    
    
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = {
            left: 550,
            top: 620
        }
        var enemies = [
        {left: 900, top: 30},
        {left: 750, top: 60},
        {left: 630, top: 140},
        {left: 480, top: 140},
        {left: 330, top: 60},
        {left: 200, top: 30},
        ]
    
        var missiles = []
    //funcion que crea los jugadores
        function drawPlayer(){
            content = "<div class='player'style='left:"+player.left+"px; top:"+player.top+"px'></div>";
            document.getElementById("players").innerHTML = content;
        }
    //se ejecuta funcion
        drawPlayer();
    //funcion crea los enemigos
        function drawEnemies(){
          content = "";
          //console.log(enemies);
          for(var idx=0; idx<enemies.length; idx++){
            content += "<div class='enemy'style='left:"+enemies[idx].left+"px; top:"+enemies[idx].top+"px'></div>";
          }
          document.getElementById("enemies").innerHTML = content;
        }
        // funcion que crea misiles
        function drawMissiles(){
            content = "";
            for(var idx=0; idx<missiles.length; idx++){
                content += "<div class ='missile' style='left:"+missiles[idx].left+"px; top:"+missiles[idx].top+"px'></div>"
            }
            document.getElementById("missiles").innerHTML = content;
        }
    
        //funcion que mueve enemigos
        function moveEnemies(){
            for(var idx=0; idx<enemies.length; idx++){
                  if (enemies[idx].top < 600 ){
                    enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top + 1;
                //console.log(enemies[idx].top);
                if(enemies[idx].top == 600){
                    window.alert("Game Over");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                  }
          }
        }
        function moveMissiles(){
            for(var idx=0; idx<missiles.length; idx++){
              missiles[idx].top = missiles[idx].top - 5;
          }
        }
    
        document.onkeydown = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 37 && player.left > 0){ //izquier
              player.left = player.left - 15;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 39 && player.left < 1120){ //derech
              player.left = player.left + 15;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 40 && player.top < 630 ){ //abajo
              player.top = player.top + 15;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 38 && player.top > 470 ){ //arriba
              player.top = player.top - 15;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 32){ //disparar
              missiles.push({left: (player.left+34), top: (player.top-8)})
              drawMissiles();
              }
            }
    
        /*  la funcion collisiondection no me funciona porque no tengo bottom, tampoco right para enemies y player, entonces es undefined?
        function collisiondetection(){
            
            for(var idx=0; idx<enemies.length; idx++){
                console.log(enemies[idx].bottom)
                if(
       (
         (player.top >= enemies[idx].top && player.top <= enemies[idx].bottom)
         ||
         (player.bottom >= enemies[idx].top && player.bottom <= enemies[idx].bottom)
       )
       &&
       (
         (player.right >= enemy.right && player.right <= enemy.left)
         ||
         (player.left >= enemy.right && player.left <= enemy.left)
       )
    ){
        window.alert("Game Over");
                    window.location.reload();
    }
            }
        }
        */
    
        function muereenemigo(){
            for(var idx=0; idx<enemies.length; idx++)
        }
        function gameLoop(){
          //console.log(drawMissiles())
          drawPlayer();
          //if(posicion actual de enemigos > parte inferior del mapa) => ejecuta moveEnemies
          moveEnemies();
          drawEnemies();
    
          moveMissiles();
          drawMissiles();
          //collisiondetection();
          //console.log(.top);
    
          setTimeout(gameLoop, 10)
        }
        gameLoop();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No añadas una respuesta como continuación de una pregunta. Edita la pregunta para modificarla. Encontraras la opción al final.